# How to launch SAVE AS FileDialog

Tags: vba, outlook, savefiledialog

I have previously written vba to open a File Dialog as a File Picker by referencing Excel `(because I understand that Outlook does not support the FileDialog object)`.  However, I am having great difficulty doing something very similar but for SAVING.

My requirement is to build a macro that will open a Save As File Dialog, with:

1) Opening at a specific folder

2) `Pre-Populate` the File Name with a `DateTime` Stamp (and allow the User to complete the rest of the name)

For the sake of explanation, I have trimmed the function code below (and I call it from a simple Testing Sub)

I am a longtime Access VBA develop[er, but am struggling as I try to write vba in Outlook and Word, so any guidance would be appreciated.

---

THIS WORKS:

```
Public Function fnOpenFileDialog_Save2(strStartingPath As String)
On Error GoTo HandleErr

    'Launch File Browser
    'NOTE:  Outlook actually does NOT support the FileDialog, so you need to hack a solution and use another Office app instead
    'This uses Excel to open the FileDialog

   Dim xlobj As Excel.Application
   Set xlobj = New Excel.Application
        With xlobj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

            .InitialFileName = strStartingPath
            .Title = "msoFileDialogOpen WORKS!"
            .Show
            'I have removed the code to select and Open Item/File as it DOES work
        End With
    xlobj.Quit
    Set xlobj = Nothing

ExitHere:
    Exit Function
HandleErr:    
    MsgBox "Error during fnOpenFileDialog_Save2 - " & Err.Description
    GoTo ExitHere
End Function
```

---

If I try to change to a SaveAs FileDialog, I cannot get anything to work.  Examples of my failures below:

```
Public Function fnOpenFileDialog_Save3(strStartingPath As String)
On Error GoTo HandleErr

   Dim xlobj As Excel.Application
   Set xlobj = New Excel.Application
        With xlobj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) 'Throws an ERROR HERE:  "Automation Error.  The remote procedure call failed"

            .InitialFileName = strStartingPath
            .Title = "msoFileDialogSaveAs does NOT work!"
            .Show
            'I have removed the code to select and Open Item/File as it DOES work
        End With
    xlobj.Quit
    Set xlobj = Nothing

ExitHere:
    Exit Function

    Public Function fnOpenFileDialog_Save4(strStartingPath As String)
    On Error GoTo HandleErr

    Dim xlobj As Application

       Set xlobj = New Application
            With xlobj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) 'Throws an ERROR HERE:  "Object doesn't support this property or method"

                .InitialFileName = strStartingPath
                .Title = "msoFileDialogSaveAs does NOT work!"
                .Show

            End With
        xlobj.Quit
        Set xlobj = Nothing

    ExitHere:
        Exit Function

Public Function fnOpenFileDialog_Save5(strStartingPath As String)
On Error GoTo HandleErr

Dim objDialog As Object
Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

        With objDialog 'Throws an ERROR HERE:  "Object doesn't support this property or method"

            .InitialFileName = strStartingPath
            .Title = "msoFileDialogSaveAs does NOT work!"
            .Show
    End With
    objDialog.Quit
    Set objDialog = Nothing

ExitHere:
    Exit Function
```

Comment: for one thing.. do you need to specify the type of application rather than just   Application

Comment: In "Save3", I used Excel and I think I did specify the Application as Excel, however I could be mistaken.

Comment: My bad. You did above.

Comment: What type of file are you trying to save? Extension?

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the filename selected. It won't actually save something. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

```
Public Function fnOpenFileDialog(strStartingPath As String) As String
    Dim strStartingPath As String
    strStartingPath = Date
    Dim xlobj As Excel.Application
    Set xlobj = New Excel.Application
    fnOpenFileDialog = xlobj.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=strStartingPath, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear.  My attempt to be concise probably failed.  I am trying to write an OUTLOOK macro, but Outlook does not support FileDialogs, so I need to invoke EXCEL and use Excel to open a FileDialog.  The problem is that I can successfully open a FileDialog this way IF I open it as FilePicker (msoFileDialogOpen).  I cannot figure out how to open the FileDialog for SAVING (msoFileDialogSaveAs).  The FileDialog has me completely confused because I just cannot figure out how to use it in these various applications??

Comment: What are you saving?